# How can I convert pytorch model to core ml model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I trained a model and got an output named model_final.pth.

I loaded the model as below.

```
#load model
model = torch.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/model/model_final.pth')
```

And I followed the below steps.

```
#load sample image
input_image = Image.open("/content/drive/MyDrive/model/g0079.jpg")
display(input_image)

to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
input_tensor = to_tensor(input_image)
input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)
```

Then when I run the code below I get an error.

```
#First attempt at tracing
trace = torch.jit.trace(model, input_batch)
```

Error:

[image]

Why am I getting this error? What do you think I should do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can find all codes here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1R85L5HpiBqc9s1DDgtf3MmPlD9iVVtWU?usp=sharing